# How to create a variable that is updated and accessible through multiple files

Tags: python, file, list, global

I'm new to python and still learning so sorry for the noob question. I am currently working on a program that spans several files, with one of them being the "main file" which is the only one that runs. I am trying to create a variable called mainList an make it accessible in all the files. I want it to be so that if I change it in one file, it is updated in others. 
I tried using global, but it doesn't update the list in all the files.
This is a very simplified version of my three files:

This is the mainFile: `#I only run mainFile`

```
import file1
import file2
file2.search(mainList)
```

This is file1:

```
import file2
class Library:
#Alot of code I will not post here, but it reads data from a file and then stores
#the instances in mainList by using a for loop and then appending to the list.
#This code reads data from a text file and stores the data in every line in a 
#different instance at an encapsulated field called data, the instances are stored 
#the mainList.
```

This is file2:

```
import file1
global mainList
mainList = []
#Alot of code I will not post here for simplicity sake
def search(LIST):
    temp = input("enter what you want to search for")
    tempList = []
    for i in LIST:
        if str(i._file1__data) == temp:
            tempList.append(i)
    for i in tempList:
        print(tempList._file1__data)
```

Comment: "other files" are modules called by the first script, I suppose. Try to pass the list as a parameter of the functions defined in that modules. (and, eventually, please show us what have you tried so far by appending some code to your question)

Comment: `global` means global to the module's namespace, not global to the execution of the program.

Comment: What exactly does this data represent? Do you want the data to persist accross instance? Maybe its better to save the data into a data file and have each script access it accordingly. Or if concurrent access is a possibility just use a database - even SQLite would do.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, The variable is a list that stores the instances of data in a class.

Comment: So the variable is a list of data. That doesn't explain much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `import` the variable or set a factory function to spit it out. For instance, if you have a directory structure like

```
project/
  __init__.py
  app.py
  config.py
```

`app.py` might need to import `mainList` from `config.py`. Well, in `app.py` just

```
from config import mainList
```

Voilà. You now have access to it in your `app.py`. You could also import the whole file and access individual variables or functions like this:

```
import config
mainList = config.mainList
```

If it's in a subdir, like

```
project/
  __init__.py
  app.py
  otherstuff/
    __init__.py
    config.py
```

You could

```
from otherstuff.config import mainList
```

But you have to have an `__init__.py` in your subdir to do so (even if `__init__.py` is completely empty).

**Update**

Well, I think what you're trying to do is keep the `mainList` in its own file and have it "stored" there with your `search(list)` function. Then you have `file1` and `file2` referencing each other (when you do that, it's called a circular import, and it's rarely what you want).

The thing is, to achieve what you want with a directory structure like this

```
app/
  mainFile.py
  file1.py
  file2.py
```

All you need to do in `mainFile.py` is

```
# mainFile.py
import file1
```

And in `file1.py`

```
# file1.py
import file2
# Maybe assign some variables for easier access
mainList = file2.mainList
search = file2.search
# And your code
class Library:
    pass
```

`file2.py` **shouldn't** depend on any information from `file1.py` or any other file higher up in the import stream, and it **should** be set up to take any list and search through it, not just one from `file1.py`. [When you import a second file that in turn imports the first file, it can cause you a lot of headaches in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) ("circular imports" as I mentioned before; info on them can be found at the bottom of the article). If what's in `file2.py` does or must depend on `file1.py`, you should really just move its contents into `file1.py`.

Now that you have access to all your data and structures in `mainFile.py`, you manipulate them however you'd like. When the interpreter runs `mainFile.py` as `'__main__'`, all it cares about is what's in `mainFile.py`. Since you imported `file1.py` and `file2.py`, they're in there and can be used in your expressions. Need to search through a list? Create an instance of `Library()` and then `search()` through it, maybe like this (`mainFile.py`):

```
# mainFile.py
import file1

library = file1.Library()
search = file1.search    # Remember we imported search() from file2.py into file1.py

# Write your logic here
```

Again, when the interpreter runs, only what you have in `mainFile.py` matters, and you have everything you need there, so you're good. `search()` and other module-specific variables, functions, methods, or properties **can't** depend on one another in the way you wrote them in your original question; if they do things start to get very messy.

Comment: Hello Chase, I am just starting with python so I don't really understand what you are saying. Could you put it in the context of the extra information I just added to my post (with the names of the three files)?

Answer (score 1):

As modules act as [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in python, you could do this:

In your `MainFile.py`

```
import tools
mainList = ["Hello", "Python"]

# this is very important to prevent circular imports!
if __name__=='__main__':
    # code...
```

Another `tools.py`

```
import MainFile
# prints out ["Hello", "Python"]
print MainFile.mainList
```

But don't do this. THIS is realy bad practice ;-)

Comment: As I am new to python I don't quite get what you are saying. Are you saying that I should put the list in a function and then import that function everywhere?

Comment: Actually, it's not a function but a module. But you got the basic idea… Anyway, better use the solution of Chase. It is more elegant.